# Remove number after duplicated number

Tags: algorithms, optimization

I created an algorithm which I cannot resolve.

Imagine you have list of number like:

```
val list = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6, 7, 2, 9)
```

And if some number is duplicated (in this case 2 is 3x times) we have to remove 3,6 and 9.
I was trying to resolve it, but I can only remove 6 and 9 and even without whole solution it looks very bad:

```
val list = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6, 7, 2, 9)
        
        val indexes = mutableListOf<Int>()
        val uniqueList = mutableListOf<Int>()

        list.forEachIndexed { index, i ->
            if (!uniqueList.contains(i)) {
                uniqueList.add(i)
            } else {
                indexes.add(index)
            }
        }

        indexes.sortDescending()

        indexes.forEach {
            list.removeAt(it + 1)
        }
```

This task is not from popular websites so I am not able to find a solution.
How to resolve it without too many loops ? My language is Kotlin but it can be java also.

Comment: Use a hash table.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comment use a hash table (map). But to be more detailed, the keys of the map will be the integers in the list while the entries will be a list containing all positions where each integer occurred.

Let `L` be your original list of integers and `M` be the map. Finally let `L'` be the new list after the removal of elements. The solution will have three phases.

In the first phase, iterate over all elements of `L` such that for each element `e` at index `i` in `L`, check if key `e` exists in `M`. If it doesn't, create a new list containing `i` and insert it in `M` with key `e`. If it does exists, then let `l` be the list in `M` for key `e`. Add `i` to `l`.

For the second phase, iterate over all list `l` in `M`. In each iteration, if the size of list `l` is greater than one, iterate over the elements of `l` such that for each element `i` in `l` set to `null` the content of index `i+1` in `L` if `i+1` is not beyond the indices of `L`.

As for the last phase, copy all non-null entries of `L` to `L'`.

The resulting list `L'` should contain all the remaining elements in order that they appear in `L`.